# Foco em um campo com maskedinput

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia, pessoal...

Tenho em meu form um campo text com entradas recursivas. Como faço p/depois de enviar um valor digitado, limpa-lo e deixar pronto para a próxima entrada ? Assim que teclo o primeiro caracter da proxima entrada ele apresenta o valor já digitado anteriormente...meu código está assim :

```
if(valor == 0){
  alert("Digitou zero.");
  document.frmsaidadoscor.txtnumdo.focus();
}else{
  dos.push(valor);
  txtnumdo.value='';
  cont = cont + 1;
  document.frmsaidadoscor.txtnumdo.focus("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para limpar o valor do campo, basta você anular o seu valor antes de realizar o foco. Já para o autocomplete do browser você pode tentar o `autocomplete="off"`, mas alguns ignoram essa instrução.

```js
let cont = 0;
let dos = [];
let input = document.getElementById('txtnumdo');

let salvar = function() {

  let valor = input.value;
  if (valor == 0) {
    alert("Digitou zero.");

  } else {
    dos.push(valor);
    txtnumdo.value = '';
    cont = cont + 1;

  }

  input.value = null;
  input.focus();

  console.clear();
  console.log(dos);
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
<input id="txtnumdo" type="text" autocomplete="false" />
<input type="button" onclick="salvar()" value="Salvar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Grato, colega....funcionou...

Comment: @Ninja2112, se a solução apresentada resolveu o seu problema você deve aceitá-la como resposta. E é importante ao fazer uma pergunta sempre se preocupar em apresentar um [MCVE]